# How to iterate a ListView items to convert in cards

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am coding an app "dash" how a startpoint to many users. "a applications dashboard". I want to convert the list of applications in cards, "portfolio style".

the user login in the platform, and in the url .../dash open the dash(django app). To here it's perfect.

with the generic view - ListView - we obtain the list of applications will be available in the platform (if exist in the model, the application it's installed and available to the user)

urls.py:

```
path('dash/', views.ListView_Dash_Apps.as_view()),
```

views.py:

```
class ListView_Dash_Apps(ListView):
    template_name = "dash/ListarAplicaciones.html"
    model = App
```

and in the html template, **How to iterate the columns of the object_list???**
with this i can iterate the rows, but not the column, i receive the ****str**** output declarated in the model.

```
<ul>
    {% for e in object_list %}
        <li>{{ e }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If i can to read the columns data and include in the html (App, url_app, icon, etc etc..)

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML, the columns are methods of the object_list.

in my case, e.appcode, e.url and e.description

```
<ul>
    {% for e in object_list %}
        <li>{{ e }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Finally:

```
{% for e in object_list %}
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="" alt="">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{e.appname}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{e.description}}</p>
            <a href={{ e.url }} class="btn btn-primary">Abrir</a>
        </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```